# Addition of functions question

Tags: functions

What is the difference between:

$(f + g)(x)$

and

$f(x) + g(x)$
?

Comment: Nothing, really. $(f+g)$ is just shorthand for the function that is the sum of $f$ and $g$ (unless you had a different meaning of $+$ in mind).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$(f+g)(x)$ is the function $f+g$ applied to the argument $x$.

$f(x)+g(x)$ is the sum of the two images of $x$ using $f$ and $g$.

That these two expressions always give the same result is the definition of $f+g$.